# update datagrid from a button click in xaml

Tags: datagrid, triggers, refresh, blend

I have in code behind

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    this.categoriesDataGrid.Items.Refresh();
}
```

The button name is "SaveButton". I'd like to do that in xaml code. I think it's posible using triggers or behaviours even blend assets pane, but I tried unsuccessfully.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got through Blend Actions

```
<Window.Triggers>
    <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="ButtonBase.Click" SourceName="button"/>
</Window.Triggers>

<Button x:Name="button" Content="Button" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="108,150,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <i:EventTrigger EventName="Click">
                <ei:CallMethodAction TargetObject="{Binding Items, ElementName=categoriesDataGrid}" MethodName="Refresh"/>
            </i:EventTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</Button>`
```